# "He took my joy away" What verb can I use to describe this?

Tags: word-request, verbs

Let's say that I've met a guy who seems perfect. We go out and we are having a great time. While we're dancing he tells me that he likes women who obey their husbands. All the magic is gone, I just want to go home and do a crossword puzzle.How can I say that he took my joy away and made me lost interest?

Comment: I'm not sure if this actually answers your question, but anyway, how about 'turn off'?

Comment: You could always say that he took your joy away and made you lose interest. If you wanted to be a bit more informal, you could try, "He sucked all the joy out of the evening and made me want to go home and do a crossword puzzle. All the magic was gone." (You're actually doing a pretty good job of describing it in your question; I'm not sure you need any elusive verb. That bit about the crossword puzzle is excellent!)

Comment: You could say that he was duller than the Monday puzzle.

Comment: You can say you gave someone else the power to decide how you feel.

Comment: "He *ruined* my plans for the evening."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were 'disenchanted' with him before the evening was over.

Comment: Of course that is not a verb.

Comment: to be "enchanted" has been watered down considerably, but originally meant to describe being under a spell (a chant).  So "disenchanted" is quite apt when "all the magic is gone". It means she was suddenly no longer under his spell. Notice how both of these terms (enchant and spell) attribute a magical power to words.